# how to detect percent similarity in two strings/word in PHP

Tags: php

I want to detect percent similarity between two words, so for example if I compare `mahatucollection` and `mahatcollect` I wanted to know the percentage of similarity between these two words? I am not trying to compare similarity of sentences, just words. Does any PHP function exists to do such thing?

Answer (score 1):

You'd use PHP's [`similar_text()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function.

```
similar_text('mahatucollection', 'mahatcollect', $percent);
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/191549)

Which warrants a return of `85.714285714286` that you could simply round using [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)